# Removing R Makevars via rm ~/.R/Makevars -- permission denied

Tags: r, macos

When I try to remove R Makevars from the macOS terminal to compile R packages as per

https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r/uninstalling-the-r-development-toolchain-on-macos/

permission is denied.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Alternatively, I can just edit the file, but permission is denied for this as well.

I am running on macOS Big Sur 11.4.

Comment: What command did you run exactly? Did you run `rm ~/.R/Makevars`? That should remove the file from your home directory. It seems unlikely that you would not have permission to edit files in your home directory. What if you run `ls -l ~/.R` what is the output? What is the permissions on that file? Does it exist?

Comment: @MrFlick I ran all commands outlined in the attached blog post through the terminal. When i tried executing `rm ~/.R/Makevars`, that's when I get the "Permission denied" message. Trying this directly in RStudio results in the same behaviour

Comment: @MrFlick When I run `ls -l ~/.R` I get `total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  376 28 Dec  2017 Makevars` There is only one file of size 376 Bytes in the directory, a Makvars from Dec 28 2017 for clang4.

Comment: Well someone that file got set to root permissions. You can try `sudo rm ~/.R/Makevars`

Comment: `sudo rm ~/.R/Makevars` worked as expected, though I have yet to test if my R packages can be successfully compiled. Thanks!